# SELECT multiple columns from multiple tables and don't fill blank spaces

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have what I believe to be a pretty unique use case. I would like to be able to runs a single `SELECT` statement on a database where I get one column from four tables. I need to run where clauses on each different table where I have one main clause that will be across each of the tables and I am not able to `JOIN` because the data in each column will be a different length and I don't want to have duplicate items.

I have an example of the Select statement below. Also I understand if this is not possible.

```
SELECT s.service_id, u.id AS "user_id", h.mac_address, l.id AS "location_id" FROM services s
LEFT JOIN db.av_product ap ON s.product_id = ap.id
WHERE s.customer_code LIKE 'test_customer'
AND u.customer_code LIKE 'test_customer'
AND h.customer_code LIKE 'test_customer'
AND l.customer_code LIKE 'test_customer'
AND s.parent_id IS NULL 
AND s.active=0
AND ap.sku NOT REGEXP 'fakeregex'
AND l.active = "1"
AND h.hardware_id NOT IN ('44','45')
AND (u.support_user != 1 OR u.support_user IS NULL);
```

**TIA!**

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use joins for your tables to make a single query OR you can try multiple queries merged with `UNION` keyword.

If you want to make a single query, have a look about `SELECT DISTINCT` or `GROUP BY` for handling duplicates.

Comment: Thanks, I looked at both of these. From everything I have read so far it seems this is not possible and I will just need for unique select statements.

Answer (score 1):

wut up?

do you know what `UNION` is?

The `UNION` operator is used to combine the result-set of two or more `SELECT` statements.

but every `SELECT` statement within `UNION` must have the same number of columns; so there we got a problem.
you can handle it with `WHERE` operator so I won't get in to it.
anyway, `UNION`!

shall we?

```
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table1
UNION
SELECT column_name(s) FROM table2;
```

anyway; your solution is `UNION`, maybe not like what I wrote.
you can try this link too.
https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_union.asp

have a clean code

Comment: Thanks, I looked into union. The main reason this will not work is because I am using 4 columns from 4 tables, each needs to be its own column, Union seems to combine all of 4 into a single column. Additionally each column is doing to be a different number of results (i.e. there are more users than devices, etc). From everything I have read so far it seems this is not possible and I will just need for unique select statements.